# Why am I getting an extra, blank, citation in my bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I need some help with my LaTeX bibliography output.

I'm using [bibtexmng](/questions/tagged/bibtexmng) and working with thirty-six (36) citations.

But, when I compile my LaTeX document to a PDF, the resulting bibliography has  *thirty-seven* (37) citations, but the first citation is simply a blank space.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]
So, how would you like me to remove that first citation so my bibliography has only the 36 citations I've specified?

---

UPDATE!!

Here is my .BIB file

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,makeidx]{skripsi}

 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{array}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \newcounter{myrow}
  \newcommand\RaiseImage[2][scale=1]{%
  \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   %\usepackage{graphicx}% delete the demo option in your actual code
   %\usepackage{enumitem}
   %\usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage[bahasa]{}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    %\usepackage{textcomp}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
    \usepackage{array}
   \usepackage{enumerate}
    %\usepackage{enumitem}
   \usepackage{subfigure}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{rotating}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{multirow}
   \usepackage{pdflscape}
   \usepackage{lscape}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usepackage{url}
   \urlstyle{same}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{etex}
   \reserveinserts{18}
   \usepackage{morefloats}
   \usepackage{float}
   %\makeindex{subject}


   \usepackage{fancyvrb}
   \usepackage{setspace}
   \onehalfspacing
   \newenvironment{CVerbatim}
   {\singlespacing\center\BVerbatim}
   {\endBVerbatim\endcenter}

    \centerchapter
    \makeatletter
    \doublespacing
    \makeatother
    \parindent 3.0em
    %===================================================================
   \setlength{\textwidth}{15.0cm}
   \setlength{\evensidemargin}{2.5cm} % outer/right margin
   %\setlength{\topmargin}{0.3cm}      % top margin
   \setlength{\footskip}{2.5cm}         % distance between text and foot
   \setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\topmargin}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
   \addtolength{\textheight}{-4cm}   % bottom margin
    %======================================================================
   \begin{document}
   \nocite{*}
   %#start bagian administrasi #==================================================
   % bagian muka sebelum isi, umumnya halaman administrasi, kalau tidak digunakan
   % dapat diberikan tanda % didepannya

   %cover
  \pagestyle{empty}
   \pagenumbering{roman}
   \setcounter{page}{1}
  \include{cover}


    %halaman lembar pengesahan, abstraksi, kata pengantar
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \setcounter{page}{2} %nilai halaman utk awal dari abstrak s/d ucapan terimakasih dlm     
      romawi
     %\include{lembarpengesahan}% menggabungkan file lembar pengesahan
     \include{abstraksi}% menggabungkan file abstraksi
   
      %menggabungkan file CV atau riwayat hidup ringkas
       %\include{cv}
       % \include{katapengantar}% mengabungkan file kata pengantar

       %# akhir bagian administrasi # ==========================================

       % #mulai membuat daftar isi, daftar gambar dan  daftar tabel # ==========
       %\setcounter{page}{8} %set nilai halaman sesuai urutannya

       % membuat daftar isi
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
       \tableofcontents{}

       %membuat daftar gambar
       \listoffigures
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List Of Figures}%masih masalah

        %% membuat daftar tabel
        \listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

         %\include{daftarlampiran}

          % #akhir membuat daftar isi, daftar gambar dan  daftar tabel # ==========

         % # mulai bagian isi # ==================================================

       \newpage
       \pagestyle{headings}
       \pagenumbering{arabic} % jenis huruf arabic
       \setcounter{page}{1} %mulai dari halaman 1


       \input{Chapter1/chapter1.tex} %Bab 1

       \input{Chapter2/chapter2.tex} %Bab 2

       %\input{Chapter3/chapter3.tex} %Bab3

       %\input{Chapter4/chapter4.tex} %Bab 4

       %\input{Chapter5/chapter5.tex} %Bab 5

       % diatas menunjukkan SubDir/nama file tex, bisa ditambah/dikurang sesuai     

       kebutuhan

        % # akhir bagian isi # ==================================================

       % # mulai bagian Daftar Pustaka # ============================================
        %\newpage\emph{}
       \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{BIBLIOGRAPHY} %memasukkan daftar pustaka di daftar  
         isi
       \bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
        \bibliography{MainTamplateSkripsi} %file menyimpan bibtex

       % # akhir bagian referensi # ============================================

        \newpage
        \pagestyle{plain}
       %\include{appendix}
       %\printindex{subject}{INDEKS}

       \end{document}
       %% Finish----------------
```

Comment: My code is only common citation code

Comment: Well, if it were, it would work, wouldn't it? We really need to see some code in order to find out where the problem lies. You could also look out for errors/warnings by LaTeX and BibTeX and check whether the your `.bib` file is well-formed. BTW: your second citation does look a bit fishy, are you sure it has to be "A. M.mansour"?

Comment: You probably have a spurious `\bibitem{}` in the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: Your code does not really qualify as a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/): It is still quite verbose and contains portions that are very unlikely to have caused the error (so it is not M); furthermore it is not compilable, we are missing the `\include`d and `\input` files (so it bis not really W). The biggest problem is obviously the missing `.bib` file. But please, try to strip down the files (delete everything that is unnecessary) before posting them here. A guess since you issue `\nocite{*}`: is there some kind of empty citation in `MainTamplateSkripsi.bib`?

Comment: I have the same issue: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/381285/latex-bibtex-is-generating-1-extra-empty-reference-on-acm-2017-journal