# LaTeX (Bibtex) is generating [1] extra empty reference on ACM 2017 journal

Tags: citing, acmart

I am using ACM 2017 edition of `.cls` for my journal:

```
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
```

using `pdflatex` on Overleaf and the below bibliography style:

```
% Bibliography
\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{acmsmall-sample-bibfile}
```

However, I am seeing an extra reference in my bibliography section having `[1]` and is empty. Can't seem to find a way to remove this extra empty reference. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe there's a stray `\cite{}` in your .tex file? (Use Ctrl+F as a quick check)

Comment: check log files for warnings. helps to narrow down the search

Comment: @LianTzeLim, I checked for that and no instances found.

Comment: @naphaneal, Checked the log file related to Bibtex, justs a bunch of warnings related to style and yet no error and other things helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and found that the problem was caused by an error in my `.bib` file.  I had written:

```
@article{perdew_82},
title = {...}, 
journal = {...},
etc., down to a final closing }
```

It worked when I used the following (note the loss of a `}` character on the first line):

```
@article{perdew_82,
title = {...}, 
journal = {...},
etc., down to a final closing }
```

Comment: +1 and welcome to our community! If that's a 1982 paper by John Perdew on DFT, you might want to join the [DFT Stack Exchange](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/density-functional-theory) :)